# links in NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I want to make links in NSTextView default not underlined, but when the mouse is over it, the underline shows. Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As of 10.3, NSTextView has [-setLinkTextAttributes:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). I'm not sure if this affects mouse over as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. The problem is not only to override the default attribute, but to change it on a mouseMoved action. What I can't figure out is how to get the text that I want to change...

Comment: Corrected my answer - even though I don't think it'll help the mouse-related stuff my initial answer was incorrect anyway. I think for mouse-over attribute changing, you're better off turning off automatic link detection and managing formatting yourself, based on the text range the mouse is over.

Comment: -setLinkTextAttributes: is not exactly what I wanted. it changes the behavior of all links in the text, not the one under the mouse. eventually I came up with the following solution: 1) subclass textview 2) override mouseMoved 3) in the attributed string, using custom attributes to mark the links, 4) in mouseMoved, get the link under mouse 5) change the attributed string to show underline, or hide the underline.